# JSPerf test case giving errors but works fine on codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance-testing, jsperf

Can anybody clue me in as to why this JSPerf test case is giving me errors? I reviewed the code several times and I can't find any mistakes. I even the code in codepen and everything ran fine.

[JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-inline-styling-vs-class-toggling)